# Java draw component on java.awtGraphics

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I have a method that creates a buffered image and I want to be able to create a progress bar and then paint that onto the buffered image. Any idea how I can achieve this please?

```
    public void paint() {
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
      JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();

      //Draw the progress bar on Graphics g ???
    }
```

Comment: Managed to answer my own question thanks, pb.paint(g) seems to work

Comment: What is the purpose of drawing the component rather than placing a functioning component on the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours appears to be an xy problem in that you really don't want to add or remove components inside of any painting method. I'm going to assume that you want to place a JProgressBar onto a component that shows an image, and to do this best, create a class that extends JPanel, override its paintComponent method, draw your image in that method override, and add your JProgressBar to that JPanel (but not within its paint or paintComponent method).

e.g.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;
    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    public MyPanel() {
        // get your image here
        add(progressBar);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();;
        if (image == null) {
            return size;
        } else {
            int w = Math.max(image.getWidth(), size.width);
            int h = Math.max(image.getHeight(), size.height);
            return new Dimension(w, h);
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g); 
         if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); 
         }
    }

}
```